# Open .m3u8 video streaming on Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video-streaming

I have a problem regarding unity 3d video stream, I want to open I can open mp4 videos but with the video player I can't open m3u8 video streams, is there a way to open this kind of videos.Is there any way to play it via u3dxt plugin

Answer (score 0):

EasyMovieTexture is able to play m3u8 format

Answer (score 0):

The [AVPro Video plugin](http://renderheads.com/product/avpro-video/) for Unity has really good adaptive video file support (both DASH and HLS/m3u8) and supports many platforms. Much easier to use compared to EasyMovieTexture as well.

Using AVPro Video and [the Vimeo Unity plugin](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk) together is also really helpful if you need to host and transcode videos to the m3u8 format.